# Xarray apply a function along 2 axis in parallel, where the input and output have different sizes

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dataset, dask, python-xarray

**Context:** I have a dataset with dimensions (`time`,`x`,`y`) and a 3D variable with the same dimensions. The dimension `time` is a 1D array of timestamps, 1 per day.
[image: dataset]

**Function:** I have an interpolation that takes a pixel from the [`x`,`y`] dimensions, and its entire length in the `time axis` (`function(dataset.values[:,0,0])` for example). This function returns a 1D array with a smaller dimension such as: `len(input)>len(output)`.

**Goal:** I want to apply this function to every pixel on `[x,y]` of my dataset (which is *chunked*) in parallel, because the function in reality is embarassingly parallel.

**Problem/question:** I tried using `u_funcs` and `apply_along_axis` to compute in parallel the function on the `x` and `y` axis. But if the output is different from the input in size, I can't make it work. How could I do that ?

**Code attempts:** There are 2 attempts. The first one is showing simply what I want to do, without chunks or anything. The second attempt uses `apply_along_axis` but does not allow me to use chunks or parallelize the computation.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

########### ATTEMPT 1 ###########
######## THROUGH A SIMPLE LOOP, NO CHUNK ############

# Create a sample dataset
dates = pd.date_range(start="2023-01-01", end="2023-05-01")
data = np.random.rand(len(dates), 10, 10)
dataset = xr.Dataset(
    {"v": (["time", "x", "y"], data)},
    coords={"time": dates, "x": range(10), "y": range(10)},
)

# Create a function that interpolates the dataset and returns values every 5 days
def interpolate_5_days(pixel):
    # Create an array of indices representing the original time steps
    original_indices = np.arange(len(pixel))
    
    # Create an array of indices representing the interpolated time steps
    interpolated_indices = np.arange(0, len(pixel), 5)
    
    # Create an interpolation function
    interpolator = interp1d(original_indices, pixel, kind='linear')
    
    # Interpolate the pixel values at the interpolated time steps
    interpolated_pixel = interpolator(interpolated_indices)
    
    return interpolated_pixel


# Create output array, will be smaller than input on the time axis
output_array = np.zeros((25,10,10))

# Run the function for each pixel in [x,y]
for i in range(output_array.shape[1]):
    for j in range(output_array.shape[2]):
        output_array[:,i,j] = interpolate_5_days(dataset.v.values[:,i,j])


###### ATTEMPT 2 #########
### WORKS BUT DOES NOT USE CHUNKS NOR PARALLEL #######

import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from tqdm import tqdm

# Create a sample dataset
dates = pd.date_range(start="2023-01-01", end="2023-05-01")
data = np.random.rand(len(dates), 10, 10)
dataset = xr.Dataset(
    {"v": (["time", "x", "y"], data)},
    coords={"time": dates, "x": range(10), "y": range(10)},
)
dataset = dataset.chunk({'time': 1, 'x': 5, 'y': 5})


def interpolate_5_days(pixel):
    # Create an array of indices representing the original time steps
    original_indices = np.arange(len(pixel))

    # Create an array of indices representing the interpolated time steps
    interpolated_indices = np.arange(0, len(pixel), 5)

    # Create an interpolation function
    interpolator = interp1d(original_indices, pixel, kind='linear')

    # Interpolate the pixel values at the interpolated time steps
    interpolated_pixel = interpolator(interpolated_indices)

    return interpolated_pixel


def process_pixel(pixel):
    output_pixel = interpolate_5_days(pixel)
    return output_pixel


# Create output array, will be smaller than input on the time axis
output_array = np.zeros((25, 10, 10))

# Apply process_pixel function along the time axis of dataset.v using apply_along_axis
output_array = np.apply_along_axis(process_pixel, axis=0, arr=dataset.v.values)

# Create output dataset with output_array
output_dataset = xr.Dataset(
    {"output_array": (["mid_date", "y", "x"], output_array)},
    coords={"mid_date": range(25), "y": range(10), "x": range(10)},
)

print(output_dataset)
```

Comment: Why does the output length differ between different 1d timeseries in your calculation?

Comment: Because I have a timeseries that has one or multiple values per day, but I am inverting it to force 1 value every 5 days. It's not really a downsampling because in reality there are a bunch of other parameters.

But the idea is that I have a function where the output is shorter than the input.

Comment: In the end all the outputs have the same length because all the inputs have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

What about `xr.apply_ufunc`?

```
output_dataset2 = xr.apply_ufunc(
    process_pixel,
    dataset.chunk(time=-1),
    input_core_dims=[["time"]],
    output_core_dims=[["mid_date"]],
    vectorize=True,
    dask="parallelized",
    output_dtypes=["float"],
    dask_gufunc_kwargs={
        "output_sizes": {"mid_date": int(np.ceil(len(dataset.time) / 5))}
    },
)
```

You can check that it's actually parallel by adding some print statements in the function to apply:

```
def process_pixel(pixel):
    print("start", end=" ")
    output_pixel = interpolate_5_days(pixel)
    print("end", end="\n")
    return output_pixel
```

Without parallelization you will get something like

```
start end
start end
start end
start end
```

With parallelization `output_dataset2.load()` results in something like

```
start end
startstart end
start  end
start endend
start end
```